# Is this prossible to change the REQUEST_METHOD with mod-rewrite?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have ask from developer where i need to change the REQUEST_METHOD based on below rewrite conditions.

```
RewriteCond %{Request_url} ^/sometext/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteCond %{HTTP:myheader} =true
RewriteRule <change REQUESTMETHOD to PUT from POST>
```

is this feasible to change the REQUEST_METHOD with rewrite rule (HTTPD version: 2.4.6)? i have tried many ways but didn't get success. Can someone help if this possible to acheive with rewrite rules